# Php - Read Excel and Strore to Db

Tags: php, arrays, excel, phpexcel

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
$inputFileName ="../brief/phaseupload/" . $filename;
//  Read your Excel workbook
        try {
            $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
        }

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 3; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
//  Read a row of data into an array
 $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
print_r($rowData);
```

I use above code to read the excel file using **PHPExcel**. I managed to read the excel value and print it. Now the problem is I need to store the values in the database. How do I get the value, in this case from $rowData?
Below is the sample output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 854273_19 [1] => Beds [2] => 61 [3] => Autumn Winter 2012 [4] => Divans [5] => Fabric [6] => Storage Bedding [7] => Single Divan [8] => Not Required [9] => Fabric [10] => White [11] => Not Required [12] => Not Required [13] => [14] => Not Required [15] => Divan With Mattress [16] => Not Required [17] => Not Required [18] => Not Required ) ) 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that you already have the number of rows on your array, you can proceed with this, inside the loop.

```
$value1 = $rowData[$row]["A"];
$value2 = $rowData[$row]["B"];
   //and so on...
```

Make sure you clean the strings as you will be inserting to the db.

Comment: I'm getting `Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in E:\Next3D\NextWeb\dao\briefupload.php on line 216`

Comment: If the call is done as `rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);` with the additional `TRUE` argument, then it will return the row/column indexes as keys to the array; otherwise it would be `$value1 = $rowData[0][0];
$value2 = $rowData[0][1];`